# Cannot convert timestamp to date type in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I get an error saying that the format is different from the ISO format and I can't seem to convert it to date type. What should I do?

```
import datetime
timestamp1='2022-03-03T14:13:52.847000+00:00'
timestamp2='2022-03-03T12:50:26.785000+00:00'

time = datetime.date.fromisoformat(timestamp1) - datetime.date.fromisoformat(timestamp2)
print(time)

ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2022-03-03T14:13:52.847000+00:00'
```

Comment: Well, this isn't ISO format. Maybe you should use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) instead

Comment: @aaossa the problem is not with ISO format, the problem is that OP is using `date.fromisoformat` - but the input contains more than a date, so use `datetime.fromisoformat`.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and only use the part that contains a date:

```
datetime.date.fromisoformat(timestamp1.split("T")[0])
```